# Node js : how to export a previously exported function to make it visible

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, systemjs

Say I have **post.js** with the following.

```
var functions = require('firebase-functions');
const express = require('express');
exports.post = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
     //stuff.
});
```

Then I just want to include this function into the main file, as it it, so that when running index.js which requires post.js, have the `post function`, already exported.

Which in the case of firebase functions would run the https function, but now it doesn't unless I explicitly do exposts.post again in the requiring file.

I tried this.

**index.js**

```
// here
exports.post = require("./post");

//Another functions ...
exports.user = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
    //stuff
});
```

But because of this, `exports.post = require("./post");`, I get `http://localhost:5000/project-id/us-central1/post-post`, which should just be `...us-central1/post`.

Also, is it possible to have the required module reference its variables from the requiring file, so that I don't have to do require in **post.js**, for variables that already exist in index.js, things like "fs" from the **file system.**

Thanks.

Comment: https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/issues/170

Comment: Ok, thanks the link, this is proper.

Answer (score 0):

Soo it seems like you are exporting post as a property. You will need to change `post.js` to:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const express = require('express');
module.exports = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
    //stuff.
});
```

Regarding your question. This is usually a bad practice. Each module needs to have its own scope. So, you should require every dependency you need in each file by using `require`. If you still want to do this, you could use global variables. [More info](https://stackabuse.com/using-global-variables-in-node-js/)